# GUI for qemu-static & chroot

Tags: linux, user-interface, qemu, chroot

Is there any standard way to have a GUI for an emulated system using qemu and chroot? 
 I searched about 'curses' , 'qtemu' ,etc. but I don't know how to use former and the latter was buggy. any suggestions ?
I'm using this command and I'm happy with bash interface:
     `LANG=C sudo chroot mnt /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -cpu cortex-a9 /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

You can always run guest machine(s) with a vncserver attached to the video console. To do this, run qemu/kvm with the -vnc option:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -cpu cortex-a9 -vnc :1
```

This will start qemu in the background with a vncserver usually listening on "localhost:5901". You cand now start a vnc client to have access to the guest GUI.

Further info here:
http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-kvm_sd_draft/cha.qemu.running.html#cha.qemu.running.vnc

Comment: I tried that ,it shows the help context meaning it's not usable in this format.

Comment: The procedure that catalin.me described worked for me on variety of configurations. Actually, I never saw it not working.